# No grub screen on a dual boot, screen blank until Ubuntu sign-on screen appears

Tags: grub2, 19.10

I have successfully installed Ubuntu as a dual boot on my HP Pavilion TP01.  All was successful with a grub screen appearing with Ubuntu first choice and Windows as third.  Have successfully kept Ubuntu and Windows updated.  Suddenly (i.e. I don't know quite when it happened), the grub screen no longer displayed and the floating "No signal" was on the screen until suddenly the Ubuntu sign-on screen appeared and Ubuntu successfully started.  I have tried estimating when the grub screen would have appeared and, using the arrow keys, I moved the selection down to where Windows would be (there was nothing on the screen) and pressed "enter".  There was a Windows ping but nothing appeared on the screen.

Since I cannot see the grub menu, I cannot select the BIOS to boot from removable drive.

Help!